# maximum likelihood - estimate $\sigma^2$ in $N(0,\sigma^2)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, statistics

Prove, using maximum likelihood, the estimation of $\sigma^2$ where $X$ is $N(0,\sigma^2)$

There is no real statistics involved, just algebra and finding partial derivatives, so I tagged it algebra and calculus as well.

$S_{xx}=n$ is obviously wrong.

**Attempt**

[image: one]
[image: two]

Answer (score 2):

You need
$$
\frac{d}{d\sigma}\left(-n\log\sigma- \frac 1 2 \sigma^{-2} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right).
$$
(I've written $x_i$ where you have $x_i-\mu$ since in this case it is known that $\mu=0$.)

The derivative is
$$
\frac{-n}{\sigma} +\sigma^{-3} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2.
$$

That differs from what you have.

$$
\frac{d}{d\sigma} \sigma^{-2} = -2\sigma^{-3}.
$$

Comment: Actually, if the parameter is $\sigma^2$, the derivative should be with respect to that, not with respect to $\sigma$... Yes, I know that, because of the chain rule (or the ML invariance) the result is the same, but still...

Comment: @leonbloy : I don't see why this matters, but enlighten me if you can.  There can be various ways to solve a problem.  If I presented it the way you suggest, it would be more complicated since I wasn't  trying to simply show how to get the answer, but rather I was trying to indicate where the given answer goes wrong.

Comment: Ok, I see my derivation error at ^-3. I do not, however, think it is correct to say $$\mu=0$$ I argued like this, please tell me if it is correct or not: We have $$\partial \ell / \partial \mu = 0$$ gives $$\mu=\bar{x}$$ which *when we substitute* into equation (*) (although edited for the ^-3 error) leads to the conclusion that we estimate $(\sigma^2)$ with $$S_{xx}/n$$

Comment: @jacob : Your question as posted tells us that $\mu=0$.  It says $N(0,\sigma^2)$, not $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @jacob : It is true that the MLE for $\mu$ is $\bar x$ if the parametrized family we're dealing with is $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  But your question as posted says $N(0,\sigma^2)$, not $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, i.e. you told us that $\mu$ is known to be $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes, I see that now. So if I change from $0$ to $\mu$ in my question, then my comment about 20 hours ago is correct?

Comment: If by $S_{xx}$ you mean $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2$, where $\bar x=(x_1+\cdots+x_n)/n$, then $S_{xx}/n$ is indeed the MLE for $\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 2):

When the variance is unknown, you might want to estimate the variance $\sigma^2$ , or to estimate the standard deviation $\sigma$ and the square it. Sometimes the result is the same, sometimes it's not. For Maximum Likelihood it happens to be [the same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Functional_invariance). But, anyway, it's good to state it clearly firsthand: which is the parameter I'm estimating?  If it's $\sigma^2$ (as you are asked here) then you should treat that as a single variable, forget about the square, think of the whole $\sigma^2$ as a single symbol, or redefine it by some letter, say $s=\sigma^2$ and estimate $s$. Then we'd have:

$$\log L(s) =  -\frac{n}{2} \log(s) + c- \frac{1}{2} \frac{ \sum x_i^2}{s} $$

where $c$ does not depend on $s$. So, derivating with respect to $s$ and equating to zero:

$$ -\frac{n}{2} \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{ \sum x_i^2}{s^2} = 0 \implies s = \frac{\sum{x_i^2}}{n}$$

So $\hat {\sigma^2}=\frac{\sum{x_i^2}}{n}$ as expected.

Notice that you could also estimate $\sigma$ (as done in MichaelHardy's answer) and square it, and the result happens to be the same. But in general (outside ML), "to estimate the variance" is one thing and "to estimate the standard deviation and square it" is another different thing.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say I estimated $\sigma$ and then squared.  Rather, the likelihood, as a function of $\sigma^2$, is also a function of $\sigma$ and can be differentiated with respect to $\sigma$.  It's a bit like those calculus problems in which you maximize an angle by maximizing the tangent of the angle, or minimize a distance by minimizing the square of the distance, thereby getting a simpler differentiation problem.  (Except that I used a different independent variable rather than a different dependent variable.)